How to determine physical size of display in centimeters
I want to know the physical size of the display in centimeters. I figure something like this should work, x axis for example:
float centimetersPerPixel = 1f / Gdx.graphics.getPpcX();
float screenWidthInCentimeters = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * centimetersPerPixel;

This appears to work for a desktop app on a retina display, but on an iPhone 15 Pro Max simulator, I'm getting a width of 4.13cm, which is too small, according to some specs published online the phone has a width of about 6.7cm, not sure of the exact screen width but 4.13cm must be too small.
These are the values of some of the relevant properties that gdx is reporting for the iPhone simulator.
Gdx.graphics.getWidth(): 430
Gdx.graphics.getDensity(): 1.65
Gdx.graphics.getPpcX(): 103.93701

Thanks
